# Shutdown computer in X amount of hours

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and am trying to write a program. I would like this program to ask me if I would like to shut down, or put my computer to sleep. Then ask me in how many minutes I would like this action to take place.

I want to create this so that I don't leave my computer on all night when I'm listening to a music or podcast in bed. So far, I have gotten it to ask me if I would like to sleep/shutdown and for how long. I'm not sure what the syntax is to put the computer to shutdown in x amount of time. If somebody could tell me how, that would be much appreciated!

```html
option = input('Enter "SD" to Shutdown or "S" to sleep: ')

if option == "SD" or option == "sd":
    print('You chose to Shutdown')
    time = input('In how many hours would you like to shutdown the PC? ')

    #   os.system("shutdown /p")


elif option == "S" or option == "s":
    print('You chose to sleep')
    time = input('In how many hours would you like to put the PC to sleep? ')
```

Comment: What Operating System are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the timeout for shutdown on **Windows** using:

```
shutdown /t xxx
```

Set the time-out period before shutdown to xxx seconds.

> The valid range is 0-315360000 (10 years), with a default of 30.
>   If the timeout period is greater than 0, the /f parameter is implied.

Also you can always look for other options for command using:

```
shutdown /help
```

In your code:

```
os.system("shutdown /t {}".format(time))
```

Comment: Note that this is Windows-specific

Comment: @JamesElderfield I think any solution will be OS-specific, but it's good to call out which OS. Too bad the question doesn't specify one.

Comment: @MarkRansom I think I should just add in my solution.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using a Windows PC. For the sleep option, would it be the same as well? os.system("sleep /t {}".format(time))

Comment: You can make this the address for a shortcut for ease of access